# AWS Set Cognito User Pool Identity Provider to Other User Pool

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-userpools

I have set my user pools to use other user pools as an OIDC IdP. I have get Endpoint from https://cognito-idp.(Region).amazonaws.com/(Pool_Id)/.well-known/openid-configuration. I have set callback url to https://www.google.com. But when I use Hosted UI to login use other user pools I get error redirect_mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AWS Hosted UI use:
`https://<your_user_pool_domain>/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com`

Comment: set in Callback url in App Client Settings or Authorization endpoint in OIDC Identity Provider?

Comment: I have User Pool 1 and I want to OIDC to User Pool 2 to sign in use User Pool 2 and create User in User Pool 1 like Google and Facebook sign in and get attributes from User Pool 2.